# Excel - nestle 3 if statements into one each has multiple conditions to be met and different actions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 if statements that each require 3 conditions to be met plus 3 different actions if met. Is it possible to put these into one statement, so it checks each one and performs the actions when it sees the right one, for example:

```
IF((AND(A2="NIKE", B2="LADIES", C2="Y")), D2*E2*1.7, "No")
IF((AND(A2="ADIDAS", B2="MENS", C2="Y")), D2*E2*2.9, "No")
IF((AND(A2="PUMA", B2="KIDS", C2="Y")), D2*E2*3.9, "No")
```

Comment: Which one of my formulas did you like in your last question?

Comment: What I am asking is, is this a one to one relationship?

Comment: This last solution is perfect. I accidentally missed off that each condition had a slightly different action needed to be performed on it. Thanks very much.

Comment: I know, but are you wanting the many to one 2nd or 3rd formula in the answer? or the one to one first formula in the answer?

Comment: If you have a lot of different conditions (more than 3 in this case and each have their own number), you may want to use some kind of reference table and lookup formulae (sumifs might be useful for instance to keep things simple)

Comment: The first answer is perfect. Thanks.  IF(AND(A2="NIKE", B2="LADIES", C2="Y"), D2*E2*1.7, IF(AND(A2="ADIDAS", B2="MENS", C2="Y"), D2*E2*2.9, IF(AND(A2="PUMA", B2="KIDS", C2="Y"), D2*E2*3.9, "No")))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IF(AND(A2="NIKE", B2="LADIES", C2="Y"), D2*E2*1.7, IF(AND(A2="ADIDAS", B2="MENS", C2="Y"), D2*E2*2.9, IF(AND(A2="PUMA", B2="KIDS", C2="Y"), D2*E2*3.9, "No")))
```

If you're OK not showing "No" then, factorize `D2*E2`:

```
D2 * E2 * IF(AND(A2="NIKE", B2="LADIES", C2="Y"), 1.7, IF(AND(A2="ADIDAS", B2="MENS", C2="Y"), 2.9, IF(AND(A2="PUMA", B2="KIDS", C2="Y"), 3.9, 0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want many to one then use:

```
=IF(AND(OR(A2={"NIKE","ADIDAS","PUMA"}),OR(B2={"LADIES","MENS","KIDS"}),C2="Y"),D2*E2*CHOOSE(MATCH(A2,{"NIKE","ADIDAS","PUMA"},0),1.7,2.9,3.9), "No")
```